# Error trying to get events in web3.py via Infura

Tags: events, ropsten, web3.py, infura, python

I was trying to get all events from my smart contract (in Ropsten) via Infura node.

The problem is that I know that Infura does no support creating filters, but I don't know how to get events by other way.

This is my method:

```
def tx_resource_smart_contract_history():
    contract = wb3.eth.contract(
        address=config.audablok_contract_address, abi=get_abi_audablok()
    )
    event_filter = contract.events.SmartContractInfoEvent.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')

    for event in event_filter:
        #Do Something

    return "TRUE"
```

The console error log is this:

```
File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/api/dataset.py", line 737, in tx_resource_smart_contract_history
    event_filter = contract.events.SmartContractInfoEvent.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/utils/decorators.py", line 16, in _wrapper
    return self.method(objtype, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1322, in createFilter
    log_filter = self.web3.eth.filter(event_filter_params)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 333, in filter
    [filter_params],
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 112, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_newFilter does not exist/is not available'}
```

Does anybody know how could I do this by other way? I mean, how could I get all events from my smart contract?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error `The method eth_newFilter does not exist/is not available` because you are not using the websocket endpoint from Infura. the `eth_newFilter` call only exists on websockets.

Change your Infura provider from:

`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID`

to:

`wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID`

Comment: I am using ropsten becouse I am still testing my sistem, ¿How could I continue using ropsten without an own node?